# Ionic infinite loader not working properly (unable to add contents)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, infinite-scroll

I am using ionic2 infinite loader simply but it doesn't seems to work properly.

```
<ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
        <ion-infinite-scroll-content loadingText="Loading more data..."></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
</ion-infinite-scroll>
```

In ts :

```
  doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {
     var test = this.documents;
     this.documents.push(test[0]);
     console.log(this.documents);
  }
```

** Issue is that initially this.documents has 11 records, and after coming in doInfinite() I am pushing 1 entry so now this.documents has 12 records I can see as in console.log(this.documents) their are 12 values now, but it shows 11 records only. any help please

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing to call the complete() method from the object.
Take a look a the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/infinite-scroll/InfiniteScroll/), you should do this:

```
doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {
 const test = this.documents;
 this.documents.push(test[0]);
 infiniteScroll.complete();
}
```